# How can I find and replace text within a Table inside a Text Box of Word Doc using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I am trying to use Powershell to find and replace some text within a Table that is inside the Text Box of a Word Document (.doc). I am able to get it working for tables, footers and headers outside of the Text box, but not if tables are inside the text box. I think it is failing because I am not correctly accessing the contents of the Text Box.

The relevant code of the script is below:

```
Function findAndReplace($Text, $Find, $ReplaceWith) {
    $matchCase = $true
    $matchWholeWord = $true
    $matchWildcards = $false
    $matchSoundsLike = $false
    $matchAllWordForms = $false
    $forward = $true
    $findWrap = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue
    $format = $false
    $replace = 2

    $Text.Execute($Find, $matchCase, $matchWholeWord, $matchWildCards, ` 
    $matchSoundsLike, $matchAllWordForms, $forward, $findWrap, `  
    $format, $ReplaceWith, $replace) > $null
}

Function findAndReplaceWholeDoc($Document, $Find, $ReplaceWith) {
    $findReplace = $Document.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find
    findAndReplace -Text $findReplace -Find $Find -ReplaceWith $ReplaceWith
    ForEach ($section in $Document.Sections) {
        ForEach ($header in $section.Headers) {
            $findReplace = $header.Range.Find
            findAndReplace -Text $findReplace -Find $Find -ReplaceWith $ReplaceWith
            $header.Shapes | ForEach-Object {
                if ($_.Type -eq [Microsoft.Office.Core.msoShapeType]::msoTextBox) {
                    $findReplace = $_.TextFrame.TextRange.Find
                    findAndReplace -Text $findReplace -Find $Find -ReplaceWith $ReplaceWith
                }
            }
        }
        ForEach ($footer in $section.Footers) {
            $findReplace = $footer.Range.Find
            findAndReplace -Text $findReplace -Find $Find -ReplaceWith $ReplaceWith
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think it is failing because I am not correctly accessing the contents of the Text Box.

Yes. The point is this.

```vb
Sub How_can_I_find_and_replace_text_within_a_Table_inside_a_Text_Box_of_Word_Doc_using_Powershell()
    
    Dim d As Word.Document, tbox As Shape, sp As Shape, tb As Word.Table
    Dim Text As Word.Find, Find As String, ReplaceWith As String
    
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    For Each sp In d.Shapes
        If sp.Type = msoTextBox Then
            Set tbox = sp
            If tbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                
                For Each tb In tbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Tables
                
                    Set Text = tb.Range.Find
                    Text.Execute FindText:=Find, ReplaceWith:=ReplaceWith, _
                        Wrap:=wdFindStop, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                        'use wdFindStop : only in the table, or all the text in Textbox will be replace
                Next tb
                
            End If
        End If
    Next sp
    
End Sub
```

I don't understand and have not tried powershell, only VBA, VB, C#, and a little C++. I think your code is probably similar in principle, but the command symbols and keywords used are different.
So I think you need to be able to "enter" the text box before you can get the content, but it can be a table or whatever, as long as it is in the text box. You probably just don't know what object or method to use to access it. so I provide you with the worked VBA code, and then you can try to convert it to powershell, which you can use.
However, I read your code, **Shape, TextFrame, TextRange** these objects you have used, should be aware of, then I do not know what is the reason. You should carefully compare my code with yours to see what the key differences are.

*The translation probably looks like this:**(I've actually tested it with Windows PowerShell and it works!** This is also my first time using Windows PowerShell. Thank you!)*

- You can directly apply. All you need is to assign the value of **$findText**, **$replaceWith**, and the **argument** of $word.Documents.**Open**() to run it. Good luck.

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $true
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("C:\path\to\your\document.docx")

$findText = "" # "Text_to_find"
$replaceWith = "" # "Replacement_text"

foreach ($shape in $doc.Shapes) {
    if ($shape.Type -eq [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType]::msoTextBox) {
        $textBox = $shape.TextFrame.TextRange
        if ($textBox.Tables.Count -gt 0) {
            foreach ($table in $textBox.Tables) {
                $findRange = $table.Range
                $find = $findRange.Find
                $find.Text = $findText
                $find.Replacement.Text = $replaceWith
                $find.Wrap = 0   # wdFindStop
                $replace = 2   # wdReplaceAll
                # $find.Execute($False, $False, $False, $False, $False, $False, $True, $find.Wrap, $False, $findText, $replaceWith, $replace, $False, $False, $False)
                $find.Execute($findText, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $True, $find.Wrap, $null, $replaceWith, $replace, $null, $null, $null)

            }
        }
    }
}

# $word.Quit()
```